# laravel download response downloads multiples folders

Tags: laravel

i want to make zip and download just 1 folder but laravel adds every files in every folder in that directory to zip file and then download it

here is my code:

```
 $license = license::findOrFail($id);
    $path = public_path() . '/Qr/subs/' . $license->system_code;

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $fileName = 'photos.zip';
    if ($zip->open(public_path($fileName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
        $files = File::files(public_path("/Qr/subs/{$license->system_code}/"));

        foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
            $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($value);
            $zip->addFile($value, $relativeNameInZipFile);
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
    return response()->download(public_path($fileName));
```

and this is what my directory looks like:

[image]

problem is that i get my license from db and get all the files in folder(folder is named with license system_code) and add it to zip file and download it, but Laravel adds every file in every folder which are in Qr/subs to zip file and then download it

what i'm doing wrong???

Comment: Why don't you use getRelativePath() in the foreach :)          foreach (File::files(..) as $file) {            $file->getRelativePath()  .. } File::files is returning array of objects not sure how basename() works with it

Comment: you mean this ? : foreach (File::files(public_path("/Qr/subs/{$license->system_code}/")) as  $file) {
                $relativeNameInZipFile = $file->getRelativePath();
                $zip->addFile($file, $relativeNameInZipFile);
            }

Comment: again it is downloading other files too @Svetoslav

Comment: ZipArchive structure for addFile ($filename, $localname = null,..)
So be careful what you set for filename I think it is more logical to replace the 2 values of relative name and full local path

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**it is solved!**

i should have deleted last zip file first and then make new one.

because laravel adds file to existing zip file

so with this line `File::delete(public_path('Qrs.zip'));` i delete it at first line of my function and then build a new one